# cfnRestApi vs RestApi[cdk]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-custom-resource

I couldn't understand from the api reference what is the real difference between these two classes:
CfnRestApi and RestApi in cdk.

As I see from documentation [CfnRestAPi](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.CfnRestApi.html) create AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi instead [RestApi](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.RestApi.html) create a REST API in Amazon API Gateway. They look like similar but I could get the differences(also because the property are similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CfnRestApi](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.CfnRestApi.html) is a low-level construct with a narrow job: create a CloudFormation `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi` resource using the CloudFormation API.  Configuration is manual and you must create related resources yourself.

Many, but not all CDK L1 `CfnFoo` constructs have a higher-level L2 `Foo` counterpart.  [RestApi](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.RestApi.html) is one such Layer 2 construct.  It adds abstractions on top of `CfnRestApi` to make building a working API easier.  It creates multiple resources for you under the hood in addition to a `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi` (a root API resource, IAM role and potentially many more depending on your configuration).

See the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html) for a general discussion of the L1, L2 and L3 (= patterns that combine L2 resources) model.